# Clipping a Geoserver raster layer with a polygon

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs, clip, wcs

I have an image mosaic raster layer with an extent that covers the contiguous United States. I also have a wfs layer with various polygons some covering subsets of the US and some outside of the US.

Essentially I'd like to have a request that returns a clipped version of the raster using one of these polygon.

As an attempt to do this I've installed the [cross layer filtering extension](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/querylayer/index.html)

The following query either returns the entire raster or none of it based on if any part of the entire geometry of the raster intersects the polygon.

```
http://geoserverinstance/geoserver/wms?&layers=gdd:agdd&styles=gdd:agdd_web,&FORMAT=image/png&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG:4269&CQL_FILTER=INTERSECTS(the_geom, querySingle('gdd:redmaple', 'geom', 'gid=1'))&bbox=-125.020833333333,24.0625,-66.479166666662,49.937500000002&width=1600&height=800
```

In the query I just pass "the_geom" for the raster layer. Is there a way for it to do the intersection on a pixel by pixel basis masking out the pixels that don't intersect?

Is it not possible to do this clipping activity using this extension? I know there is also a wps extension that might do it, but I've had issues installing it. So if this won't work I can go back to trying to figure those issues out.

Comment: Maybe that just works for [vector features](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144804/geoserver-wms-filtering-clipping-geometry-against-a-polygon)?

Answer (score 2):

Cross layer filtering does indeed work only for vector features. You can try your luck with the Crop process. There is no documentation on how to use it as a rendering transformation, but its direct WPS usage looks like it could be a match for your requiements:
http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/wps/chaining_processes.html