# GeoServer WPS built-in functions vs. GDAL utilities

Tags: geoserver, gdal, wps

I have been doing a series of back-end GIS operations such as:

- Clipping a raster file by using user's inputs (i.e. bounding rectangle)
- Returning a styled WMS based on the new raster file.

By using GDAL utilities for the clipping and Curl within PHP for the GeoServer response, and OpenLayers for the front-end.

The above works fine.

But now I would like to turn that into a simpler architecture, so is it possible to use WPS for creating the clipped raster in the server and immediately generating a WMS based on that. In other words, can I do the whole process within GeoServer and without using GDAL utlities?

I am new to the WPS aproach, so far I haven't found how to do the clipping, creating the workspace, the datastore, the layer and the styling, and publish a new WMS back to the user, all in one go.

Comment: look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211244/clipping-a-geoserver-raster-layer-with-a-polygon or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102656/doing-crop-coverage-with-wps-chain-in-sld